# Perform search through table and through other tables what are conected with foreign key in SQL Server and how to sort data

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

First time doing such complicated search query, so if you could suggest me best way. I have table insurance policy:

```
+---------+-------+---------+-------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------+
|policy_ID|USERID |INSURANCE| PRICE |START_DATE|END_DATE  |POLICY_TYPE|EMPLOYE    |NOTE       |GROUPID |
+---------+-------+---------+-------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------+
| 1       | 1     | 1       | 1000  |2019-11-27|2019-11-27|1          |1          |OUR CLIENT.|1       |          
| 6       | 2     | 2       | 10500 |2019-11-27|2019-11-27|2          |2          |OUR CLIENT.|1       |
| 2       | 3     | 3       | 1000  |2019-11-27|2019-11-27|5          |3          |OUR CLIENT.|2       |
| 3       | 4     | 4       | 120020|2019-11-27|2019-11-27|4          |4          |OUR CLIENT.|1       |
| 4       | 5     | 5       | 500   |2019-11-27|2019-11-27|4          |5          |OUR CLIENT.|1       |
| 5       | 6     | 6       | 750   |2019-11-27|2019-11-27|5          |6          |OUR CLIENT.|2       |
| 7       | 7     | 7       |       |2019-11-27|2019-11-27|5          |4          |OUR CLIENT.|1       |
+---------+-------+---------+-------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------+
```

In this table, I have foreign keys insurance, policy_type and employee. UserID is some kind of foreign key but I didn't declare it. User id can be normal person or company and information what it is is in column groupID 1 = normal user 2 = company.

In my ASP.NET search form I created search textbox and filters as dropdownlist insurance, policy_type, employee and price range maybe i will add some date range.

Now big question: how would you perform search through this table and all other tables with foreign keys? I will show the results in a gridview. For this other tables I would not search through all columns maybe just one or two columns like name or surname. Also I would like sort by active and inactive policies. Active policies are if they are end_date > current_day.

Other tables looks like:

**Clients**    // Companies // Employee

```
|client_ID|NAME |SURNAME|ETC|
+---------+-----+-------+---+
| 1       |John |Doe    |   |        
| 6       |John |Doe    |   |
| 2       |John |Doe    |   | 
+---------+-----+-------+---+
```

**Insurance**  // Companies

```
+---------+-----+
|client_ID|NAME |
+---------+-----+
| 1       |John |       
| 6       |John |
| 2       |John | 
+---------+-----+
```

Thanks you for your help.

**Edit 1**

Can you suggest me logic how you do or SQL query?
Regards
**Edit 2**

So I decided that I will first look if search term can be find in Insurance_Policy table and with inner joins I will change foreign keys. With IF clause O count if there are some result.

I got my first problem solved nad my query looks like this:

```
    declare @term nvarchar(50)
    set @term='something';
    if (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM Police WHERE policy_ID LIKE '%'+@term+'%' OR note LIKE '%'+@term+'%')>0
BEGIN
 SELECT p.policy_ID,CONCAT(c.name,' ',c.surname) as client,p.price,p.start_date,p.end_date,pt.name,CONCAT(e.name,' ',e.surname)as employee,i.name,p.note
 FROM Insurance_Policy p
 INNER JOIN
 Clients c
 ON p.userID=c.client_ID
 INNER JOIN
 Policy_Type pt
 ON p.policy_type=pt.typeID
 INNER JOIN
 Employees e
 ON p.employee=e.employeeID
 INNER JOIN
Insurance i
 ON p.insurance=i.insuranceID
 WHERE p.groupID=1 AND (p.policy_ID LIKE '%'+@term+'%' OR p.note LIKE '%'+@term+'%')

 UNION

 SELECT 
 p.policy_ID,co.name,p.price,p.start_date,p.end_date,pt.name,CONCAT(e.name,' ',e.surname)as employee,i.name,p.note
 FROM Insurance_Policy p
 INNER JOIN
 Companies co
 ON p.userID=co.client_ID
 INNER JOIN
 Policy_Type pt
 ON p.policy_type=pt.typeID
 INNER JOIN
 Employees e
 ON p.employee=e.employeeID
 INNER JOIN
Insurance i
 ON p.insurance=i.insuranceID
 WHERE p.groupID=1 AND (p.policy_ID LIKE '%'+@term+'%' OR p.note LIKE '%'+@term+'%')

END
```

Next problem with I am going to deal is what if there is no string in this table then I need to search in other tables and get results.

Any suggestion would be great. Hope that my problem is now clearer

Comment: Not really sure what you are expecting for an answer here?!?!? Are you asking how to write a where clause? Are you asking how to write the .net code?

Comment: I am expecting that someone advise me what logic are you using for this type of problem. My idea that I am working on is to make temporary table and search in that table?? If you whould like help me with code then i prefer where clause with .net am ok.

Comment: Are you saying you don't know how to write a where clause or that you need help with this exact one? There are so many examples of search queries all over the place. And we can't really help much here because your requirements are so vague. You basically write a query with joins to the tables that contain the information you want to display or filter. Then add a where clause to find the values you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell exactly what you want.  You are trying to join to two different tables, one with a surname, and one without.  In such a case, you will need two separate queries, and then union them together.  Best as I can figure from your description, it sounds like something along these lines:

```
SELECT c.name, c.surname, op.*   --actually list columns you want
FROM Insurance_Policy op
INNER JOIN 
Clients c 
ON op.user_id = c.client_id
WHERE op.Group_ID = 1

UNION

SELECT co.name, NULL, op.*   --actually list columns you want
FROM Insurance_Policy op
INNER JOIN 
companies co
ON op.user_id = co.client_id
WHERE op.Group_ID = 2
```

Comment: This helped me. I put solution in edit

Comment: This question has been marked closed.  You will not get any more answers here.  Accept my answer to this question here, and post a new question, but work on clarifying what it is you are asking.